# Rounded corners on collapsed table border

Tags: html, css-tables

I've figured out exactly how to make a thinner border for a table, but am struggling to make the borders perfect. I want rounded corners but it doesn't seem to help when I collapse the borders (to make them thin and one), and it works perfectly fine without collapsing, but then the table looks off. Help?

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Yx865/

The main focus lies here:

```
.myData .myTable table{
   border-collapse:collapse;
   border-top-right-radius:20px;
   border-top-left-radius:20px;
   border:1px solid black;
}
```

Comment: I would not use the PHP tag unless it's absolutely relevant (actual PHP code included). The PHP community on here will tear your question to pieces.

Comment: it's for a database-based project i'm working on, where information will be plugged into a viewing table. is that not a smart thing to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep the border, just make sure to hide the overflow

```
overflow: hidden;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/n2hB3/

Comment: hey can you send another jsfiddle? it says that one doesn't exist?